# Statistics and Memory

Tags: probability, inference

Suppose I have a friend who works 2 consecutive days and then has 2 consecutive days off (this pattern repeats forever). Suppose I met him 6 weeks ago on one of his days off - but I can't remember if the day that I met him, he was on first day off or if he was on his second day off.

I want to know if he is free today. Without calling him - can my guess only have a 50% chance of being correct?

Thanks

Comment: If you met him on day 1, and you are now on day 43 (42+1) then he is 100 % off. If, however, you are now on day 42, then it is 50 %.

Comment: It depends on how you guess.  There are only four circumstances to consider, so why not look at all four and determine the optimal guess?